# Improvement in messages between parties in different time zones

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I occasionally receive job offers via SO's Careers and each time such offer come I need to bend my brain a bit to ensure I got sender's time zone right. And this is quite important in business contacts. For now, when one receives a message, time stamp shown on the screen is using your (recipient's) time zone. This can easily cause some problems if you are unaware, wrongly assume different timezone, or simply won't pay much attention. Sample situation: let's imagine you just sent a message "*Let's have a call tomorrow at 10:30*" to your potential employee. You are residing in California (PDT) and your clock shows May 13th, 5pm. But the recipient is in Europe (and you cannot tell that if his profile does not specify this). His clock shows 2am of... **May 14th**. So the "*tomorrow*" can be easily interpreted by recipient as his tomorrow, which means "Sunday" while sender really meant his tomorrow, which unfortunately is "Saturday". I'd be then extremely useful if, in case both sender and recipient are in different time zones, time stamp in both time zones could be visible (adding day name would also be useful too).

Comment: Impress your future employer by either using UTC or going through the extra effort of quoting his local timezone name correctly.  The latter is always best.

Comment: I pretty much doubt you can impress anyone with your time zones skills but at the same time I am pretty much sure that the situation from my post (which is actually real one) can cause you problems. It's not that hard to took "tomorrow"  wrong at 2am, as is not that hard to add support for the requested feature to SO to simplify usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve all communication problems with technology.

Someone sending a message at 2 A.M. (or 02:00) saying "tomorrow" is being ambiguous. In my book, it is only "tomorrow" after I've slept in a bed (I may have missed some days in my life through that), and they might mean the same. They could also really mean "the day after today".

When making appointments, one should mention the date. When specifying a time in an context where different timezones (could) apply, one should mention the timezone they intend.

Comment: In ideal world, true. But things sometimes look different. The information that other side is in different timezone would be simply helpful addition.